# Office 2010 professional plus Business contact manager?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, contacts, business-contact-manager

Does Office 2010 Professional plus come with Business contact manager? If so how do I enable?

Answer (score 2):

[BCM](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/CH010373050.aspx) Microsoft has a download available here.  Have you tried that install?

From the MS site-
If you purchased a previous version of a Microsoft Office suite or a standalone edition of Microsoft Office Outlook that included Business Contact Manager, you can download Business Contact Manager for Outlook 2010 at no additional cost. You can also download Business Contact Manager for Outlook 2010 if you purchased one of the following the following products.

Microsoft Office Home and Business 2010
Microsoft Office Professional
Microsoft Outlook 2010 (stand-alone edition)